# If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, and $n < q^{k+1}$, does it follow that $k > 1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, conjectures, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$.  According to Dickson (as pointed out recently by Beasley), Descartes conjectured $k=1$ in a letter to Mersenne in 1638, with Frenicle's subsequent observation occurring in 1657.  In recent times, [Sorli (page 89)](https://opus.lib.uts.edu.au/handle/2100/275) conjectured that $k=1$ in his PhD thesis titled **Algorithms in the study of multiperfect and odd perfect numbers**.

Following [Brown](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591)'s recent announcement of a proof for $q < n$, and a partial proof that $q^k < n$ holds under many cases, I recently realized that the biconditional
$$q < n \iff \sigma(q) < \sigma(n) \iff \dfrac{\sigma(q)}{n} < \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q}$$
would follow suit, if Brown's proof for $q < n$ is correct. (Similarly,
$$q^k < n \iff \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \iff \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
would follow, if $q^k < n$ is true.)

In this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713035), I asked the following question (back in March 2014):

> If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, if $n < q^{k+1}$, does it follow that $k > 1$?

Brown actually proves $q < n$ by proving $k = 1 \implies q < n$, so that we obtain that the implication
$$k = 1 \implies \sigma(q) = \sigma(q^k) < n$$
holds, since $q < n < q+1 = \sigma(q)$ is impossible.  By the contrapositive, $n < \sigma(q^k) \implies k > 1$.

My question here is:  To what extent can we then prove that $n < q^{k+1} \implies k > 1$?  I note that $n < \sigma(q^k) \implies n < q^{k+1}$, but the converse may not necessarily be true.

Notice that the implication $$n < q^{k+1} \implies k > 1$$ will prove that $$q^2 < n,$$ since it is known that $$n < q^2 \implies k = 1.$$